# wordpress login popup box appear instead of login page

Tags: wordpress

I install WordPress in my hosting, but when I try to enter the backend a sign-in popup box appears instead of the login page. The WordPress version is 6.0.2 and it's fresh not a single work done.

This is the popup box when I trying to go domain/wp-admin

[see image](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1AzzcwIpxUVMLxQedZKe3_TC3Xb-VsFEG/view?usp=sharing)

How can I appear as usual login page not popup box?

Answer (score -1):

By default, this item is not active in WordPress. or enabled through a security plugin or host.

You can check your host in this way:

https://forums.cpanel.net/threads/cannot-remove-password-protection-in-cpanel.521111/

https://www.milesweb.com/hosting-faqs/remove-password-protection-directories-directadmin/